# Do we say "there is a hole in the site" or "there is a hole on the site"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

If you look at "**site**" in any dictionary

We always use "**on**" before "**site**"

For example, *Nothing can be built on this site.*

And, If you look at "**hole**" in any dictionary.

We always use "**in**" after "**hole**"

For example, *She drilled a small hole in the wall.*

Now, if we combine these 2 words together, there will be a dilemma.

Do we say "**there is a hole in the site**" or "**there is a hole on the site**"?

Comment: What do you mean by "hole" and "site" here? I'm having trouble visualising the context, but if it's a *building* site where someone has dug a hole (for drainage, or whatever), you'd probably go for the "surface" reference *(**on**)* rather than the "container" allusion *(**in**)*. But that's a *very* unusual context, so there's little point in thinking about "established, **correct**" usage.

Comment: ...see [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+hole+in+the+ground%2Ca+hole+on+the+ground&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) showing that although *a hole **on** the ground* virtually "flatlines" in comparison to *hole **in** the ground*, that in no way implies that [*hundreds of written instances of the former*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+hole+on+the+ground%22) are somehow "invalid" or "substandard".

Comment: "There's a hole **in** the ground **on** the building site"?

Comment: In many cases I'd say "**at** the site" is more idiomatic, but as Kate says we need more context.

Comment: *I read the news today, oh boy  ... Four thousand **holes in Blackburn,** Lancashire*

Comment: Your generalizations about prepositions such as **in** and **on** are incorrect.  *She drilled a small hole **through** the wall,* is perfectly fine.  *Nothing can be built **next to** this site,* is also perfectly fine.  When it comes to preposition usage, *always* never applies.

Comment: "Do we say [...] ?" — No, we don't.   
;)

Comment: Kindly answer questions posed to you regarding meaning from potential respondents. Thank you.  Oil rig (Australia): There is a collapsed hole **at** the bloody site, mate. :)

Comment: And: We always use "in" after "hole". No, we don't because holes can be at places.

Answer (score 0):

We say "there is a hole in the site." This is because "in" is used to indicate that something is contained within a larger area or space, while "on" is used to indicate that something is in contact with the surface of an object. In this case, the hole is within the boundaries of the site.

Comment: Sounds like a hole at the site.